# How to SELECT a column in a row and return another row if it doesn't exists?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to write a query with two SELECT Statements in an order that if the first SELECT Statement doesn't return anything then only the second select statement runs.

```
SELECT col1 FROM MyTable WHERE col2=5
```

and if this doesn't return anything(there is no col2=5) then:

```
SELECT col3 FROM myTable WHERE col4=10
```

How should it be done?

Comment: Just put `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0` between the statements. Better to wrap second statement with `begin - end`.

Comment: @yahor that could potentially return two resultsets though, in the case where the first one is empty. I assume the motivation here is around laziness about making the application care about having more than one resultset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is incredibly inefficient and I fail to see the point, but...

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ... <1st clause>)
BEGIN
  SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE <1st clause>;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE <2nd clause>;
END
```

Or if the types of col1 and col3 are compatible then...

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE <1st clause>
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE <2nd clause>
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE <1st clause>);
```

I don't know of any other way for SQL Server to determine there will be no rows from a query without actually running the query.